# Apply changes to Web App Manifest on an installed PWA

Tags: html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

If I want to make changes to my Progressive Web App, e.g. a slight change on the app name, or update the logo, is it possible to force an update on all my users' installed apps?

I tried adding "?v=2" to the manifest URL,

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?v=2" />
```

And also forced an update on the service worker.

However, it doesn't seem to apply the new changes on the installed app.
I tried this on Google Chrome on Android.

Comment: Did you try changing the name of the manifest file - e.g. `manifestv2.json`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forcing the update explicitly is not possible as per [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/). However, there's an ongoing [discussion](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/446) about it.

Are you completely sure your manifest.json wasn't served from the browser's cache? Or that the browser was actually served with the new HTML that referenced the renamed manifest.json?

My understanding was that you should just change the name (based on the content's hash, for instance) and let the browser do it's job. The spec says this way the browser should always request the new version. Not sure if the update should kick in immediately or before the next visit. However, I could be wrong.